# Lines appear when I texture a model

Tags: texturing, uv, lines

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to make a model for something, but when I texture it, these black/white lines come up. Anyone know a fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Hello & Welcome! I'm sure there is someone here who can answer this question if you would additionally reveal what "something" is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, if I go to layout or texture paint tabs, the lines don't show.

Edit: I think the lines were there because I had cavity turned on

Comment: Would you please be so kind and edit both your question and your answer to elaborate on exactly what the problem is here, and how exactly the problem could be solved? Otherwise, I would close this post, as it basically contains too little information to be helpful to others in any way. Thank you!